# How to see entire sendmail queue?

Tags: linux, sendmail

I can't see a list of queued messages on my linux server.  "sendmail -bp" only will show the first 10 for some reason:

> /var/spool/mqueue (36 requests, only 10 printed)
>   -----Q-ID----- --Size-- -----Q-Time----- ------------Sender/Recipient-----------
>   vB22bgke015365-    5857 Fri Dec  1 21:37 <>
>                    (Deferred: Connection timed out with address.com)
>                                             ...

how do I list all 36 items at once?  instead of this limit of 10?  my sendmail version is 8.14.7.

Comment: What is reported by `grep -i maxqueue /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`? Is `MaxQueueRunSize` set to `10`?

Comment: MaxQueueRunSize is set to 10, but I should be able to see the total queue. I don't even have mailq. where do I get that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `mailq` or you can list the files in queue:

```
cd /var/spool/mqueue/
ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Type the `mailq` command to see the existing queue.